Mitsubishi PA10-7c information
I have inherited a Mitsubishi PA10-7c robotic arm with a PA10-7C-CNT 100V RO controller and a ProFace GP2401h Pendant. the pendant has a connection for the controller and an RS232 connector which I assume connects to a plc. On startup the pendant says "enter wrun" with no indication of how to do so. I have located the programming manual, but there is very little reference to the pendant or connections to a computer or anything. I have reached out to Mitsubishi, but have only encountered silence. I am currently looking for any other information/software, or just to see if it actually moves.
I would be extremely grateful for any information about it.
